# Iterating over an array within another array in Javascript and showing items in UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm in the process of creating a quiz app using Javascript and can't work out how to get the multiple choice answers to show in the `ul`. They're all currently appearing in one `li` and I need them split across each one. I'll also be including an image with each `li` so have set up the HTML and CSS to ensure these are displayed correctly.

The HTML contains the text mainly as a placeholder, and I've only copied in one of the questions in the allQuestions array in the JS code.

```js
var i = 0;
var j =0;
var allQuestions = [ {
    questionNumber: 1,
    question: 'Who is the most successful manager of Manchester United?',
    options: ['Sir Matt Busby', 'Louis Van Gaal', 'Ryan Giggs', 'Sir Alex Ferguson'],
    answer: 3,
    info: 'Sir Alex Ferguson was the manager of Manchester United for 26 years between 1986 and 2013. During that time he amassed 38 trophies including 13 Premier League titles, five FA Cups and two UEFA Champions League titles. His win rate was nearly 60 per cent, the highest of any manager in the history of the club.'
}];


//start quiz and generate first question//
$('#go').on('click', function() {
    $('.start').hide();
    generateQuestions();

});

function generateQuestions() {
    $('.question-container').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.submit').fadeIn(1000);
    var firstQuestion = allQuestions[i].question;
    $('.question').html(firstQuestion);
    console.log(firstQuestion);
    var firstNumber = allQuestions[i].questionNumber;
    $('.question-number').html("Question" + " " + firstNumber);
    console.log(firstNumber);
    /*var firstOptions = allQuestions[i].options;
      $('li').html(firstOptions);
      console.log(firstOptions);*/
};

//submit answer and show answer modal//
$('.submit').on('click', function() {
    $('.answer-overlay').show();
    submitAnswer();
});

function submitAnswer() {
    $('.answer-overlay').show();
    var currentAnswer = allQuestions[i].answer;
    $('.answer').html(currentAnswer);
    console.log(currentAnswer);
    var currentInfo = allQuestions[i].info;
    $('.answer-info').html(currentInfo);
    console.log(currentInfo);
};

//hide answer modal and show next question//
$('.next-question').on('click', function() {
    nextQuestion();
});

function nextQuestion() {
    $('.answer-overlay').fadeOut(1000);
    if(i>allQuestions.length -1) {
        i=0
    }
    generateQuestions(i);
    i++

    var nextQuestion = allQuestions[i].question;
    $('.question').html(nextQuestion);
    console.log(nextQuestion);
    var nextNumber = allQuestions[i].questionNumber;
    $('.question-number').html("Question" + " " + nextNumber);
    console.log(nextNumber);
    /*var nextOptions = allQuestions[i].options;
      $('li').html(nextOptions);
      console.log(nextOptions);*/
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="question-container" id="question-container">
<h2 class="question-number">Question 1</h2>
<h3 class="question" id="question">Who is the most successful manager of Manchester United?</h3>
<ul class="answers-container" id="answers-container">
 <li class="options" id="pic1">Sir Matt Busby</li>
 <li class="options" id="pic2">Louis Van Gaal</li>
 <li class="options" id="pic3">Ryan Giggs</li>
 <li class="options" id="pic4">Sir Alex Ferguson</li>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allQuestions[i].options.forEach(function(answer,index){
        $("#pic"+(index +1)).html(answer);
    console.log(answer);
});
```

Just [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) through each of the answers individually.
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spm52zyy/)

Comment: @Ryca77 Glad I could help. Feel free to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped solve your problem, instead of using the comment section - as per rules. Have a good time at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to work for me. (I added a runnable snippet into OP for you to check)

---

**Edit**: Ok, I see that was the placeholder text being shown.

`$('li').html(firstOptions);` is your problem. You should instead be looping through firstOptions (as it is an array) and setting each `li`'s content individually. The same applies for nextOptions.

Something like below will work.

```js
var i = 0;
var j =0;
var allQuestions = [ {
    questionNumber: 1,
    question: 'Who is the most successful manager of Manchester United?',
    options: ['Sir Matt Busby', 'Louis Van Gaal', 'Ryan Giggs', 'Sir Alex Ferguson'],
    answer: 3,
    info: 'Sir Alex Ferguson was the manager of Manchester United for 26 years between 1986 and 2013. During that time he amassed 38 trophies including 13 Premier League titles, five FA Cups and two UEFA Champions League titles. His win rate was nearly 60 per cent, the highest of any manager in the history of the club.'
}];


//start quiz and generate first question//
$('#go').on('click', function() {
    $('.start').hide();
    generateQuestions();

});

function generateQuestions() {
    $('.question-container').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.submit').fadeIn(1000);
    var firstQuestion = allQuestions[i].question;
    $('.question').html(firstQuestion);
    console.log(firstQuestion);
    var firstNumber = allQuestions[i].questionNumber;
    $('.question-number').html("Question" + " " + firstNumber);
    console.log(firstNumber);
    var firstOptions = allQuestions[i].options;
    var k;
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      $('#pic'+(k+1)).html(firstOptions[k]);
    console.log(firstOptions);
};

//submit answer and show answer modal//
$('.submit').on('click', function() {
    $('.answer-overlay').show();
    submitAnswer();
});

function submitAnswer() {
    $('.answer-overlay').show();
    var currentAnswer = allQuestions[i].answer;
    $('.answer').html(currentAnswer);
    console.log(currentAnswer);
    var currentInfo = allQuestions[i].info;
    $('.answer-info').html(currentInfo);
    console.log(currentInfo);
};

//hide answer modal and show next question//
$('.next-question').on('click', function() {
    nextQuestion();
});

function nextQuestion() {
    $('.answer-overlay').fadeOut(1000);
    if(i>allQuestions.length -1) {
        i=0
    }
    generateQuestions(i);
    i++

    var nextQuestion = allQuestions[i].question;
    $('.question').html(nextQuestion);
    console.log(nextQuestion);
    var nextNumber = allQuestions[i].questionNumber;
    $('.question-number').html("Question" + " " + nextNumber);
    console.log(nextNumber);
    var nextOptions = allQuestions[i].options;
    var k;
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      $('#pic'+(k+1)).html(nextOptions[k]);
};

generateQuestions(); // added for snippet
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="question-container" id="question-container">
<h2 class="question-number"></h2>
<h3 class="question" id="question"></h3>
<ul class="answers-container" id="answers-container">
 <li class="options" id="pic1"></li>
 <li class="options" id="pic2"></li>
 <li class="options" id="pic3"></li>
 <li class="options" id="pic4"></li>
</section>
```

Comment: Isn't that just the html showing? I need the list to populate once I take away the placeholder text. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a point to declaring a var k without assignment? Why not just `for(var k = 0;k < firstOptions.length; k++)`?

Comment: `for(var k = 0 ...` comes down to preference. I like declaring var k before because in both cases you have access to k outside of the loop. (maybe let would be better to achieve block scope but I don't see that much)

Comment: (let/JS1.7 doesn't seem to have full adoption yet so I guess that's why I rarely see it: http://caniuse.com/#search=let)

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Both of these solutions do what I need - would either of you be able to explain the difference between them? Thanks.

Comment: Using a for loop to start from the array element at index `0` up to the element at index `length` will achieve the same behaviour as forEach. The only difference is that I chose to use a constant of `4` rather than length, which ideally I would define as a constant variable somewhere. This forces there to be 4 and exactly 4 options to be set - less in the array will cause an error, more will ignore the extras. Using forEach would give you an error if you had more than 4 options (as #pic5 doesn't exist), but would 'succeed' with 3 options by only setting the first 3 `li` values.